# Why use a reference volume for leak testing?

Tags: product-testing

An accepted method of leak testing a test piece is by using a differential measurement between it and a reference such as in the schematic [here](https://www.tqc.co.uk/our-services/leak-testing/useful-information/leak-testing-basic-principles/) - why might one bother doing this as opposed to just comparing your test piece alone to a predefined or recorded leak rate, or curve?

Comment: I would imagine for the sake of speed and accuracy, especially for large vessels/pipes.  Using some of the "classic" methods like pressure decay, vacuum decay or hydrostatic tests can take forever with a really small leak or a large volume (large pressure vessel or long pipeline) and also gets progressively less accurate the larger the volume/vessel tested.

Comment: @gwyn good point, I think being able to get more accurate and precise decay rates by doing it differentially rather than just a gauge measurement  is probably the main reason in reality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressures change in a vessel based on ambient conditions.  The reference volume removes that source of error.